# React vs. Angular Component Rendering

Tags: reactjs, angular, virtual-dom

I'm trying to understand component re-rendering in react vs. angular. My understanding is as follows:

React uses Virtual DOM. This is an object in memory that models the DOM. Each time some state changes, the new object is compared to a snapshot of the old component. Those changes are then synced with the real DOM, with only the affected nodes being changed.

Angular uses incremental DOM. This is also some object in memory that models the DOM, but the object is updated in place on object changes. Those changes are then also synced with the real DOM, with only the affected nodes being changed.

What I don't understand is why react components constantly re-render. For example the following:

```
export const myComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  const onClick = () => {
    setState(state + 1);
  };

  console.log("re-render");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>My Component</h1>
      <button onClick={onClick}>The button has been clicked: {state} time(s)</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

will cause the entire component to be re-rendered every time.

However, with a similar angular component, where the html is as follows:

```
<h1>My Component</h1>
<button click="onClick()">click here</button>
```

and the ts is as follows:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  buttonClick : int 

  constructor() { this.buttonClick = 0 }

  ngOnInit() { }
  
  onClick() {
   this.buttonClick += 1 
  }
}
```

the component will not re-render. Only the html binding will be updated.

Is my understanding correct? If so, why do react components re-render constantly? Does this have anything to do with the Virtual DOM vs. Incremental DOM? Or is it just the way the react and angular are designed?

Thanks!

Comment: in your react piece of code no new html elements will be created after clicks, only new click listener will replace the old one (because no useCallback is used). you can't get rid of "rerenders" in react. that is how framework works. and by "rerender" here I mean recreating piece of virtual dom, not the real dom

Comment: in angular version your understanding is correct. there is a lot of things happening in more complex examples, but nothing tricky here. if you try to observe component after it is built, you'll see that there will be a line of code for every binding in a template created to make efficient update if a property changes

Comment: Where would you put this `console.log("re-render");` in the Angular example?

Comment: @robert it would be in the constructor or ngOninit (this is the lifecycle hook for when a component is initialized). "re-render" would only be seen once in the example.

Comment: @Andrei , so I suppose that re-rendering is not inherently bad if your component is designed in a well principled manner? But re-rendering is a necessary part of creating a new object in memory to replace the current one, and in turn update the dom?

Comment: yeah, react "rerenders" aren't that heavy. most of it is happenning at the virtual dom and that is why it has virtual dom basically. In case you want to see console.log at pretty much same moments of time that reacts rerenders are called, you would put them in `ngDoCheck`. but it is slightly more complex, as not in all cases component's template is checked, even if ngDoCheck is called